# RecyclerView not updating after creating or deleting playlists in Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet, playlist

I am trying to update my recyclerView by *notifyDataSetChanged()*. But it's not working. I have to close my specific **fragment** and open it to see the changes.

This is *MyFragment* where I call recyclerView

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
    // showing Playlist Names
    recyclerPlayListViewName = 
    bottomView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_play_list_view_name);
    playlists = new ArrayList<Playlist>();
    PlayListMethodHolder.getplaylistList(getContext(), playlists);
    playlistAdapter = new PlaylistAdapter(bottomView.getContext(), playlists,
            "bottomsheet");
    recyclerPlayListViewName.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerPlayListViewName.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerPlayListViewName.setAdapter(playlistAdapter);
    playlistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This is *AdapterClass* where I call to *delete the playlist* method.

**PlaylistAdapter.java**

```
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
 long plistID =  playlists.get(position).getId();
 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case R.id.pPlay:
 break;
 case R.id.pRename:
     String dpType = "playlistRename";
     PlayListPopDialog popDialog = new PlayListPopDialog(mContext,
                                   dpType, plistID, playlists);

     popDialog.show();
     break;

 case R.id.pDelete:
     PlayListMethodHolder.deletePlaylist(mContext, plistID);
     break;
```

And This is another *DialogView* where I call *Create PlayList*

**PlayListPopDialog.java**

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_playlist_save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

    EditText edtCreateNamePlaylist = findViewById(R.id.edt_create_name_playlist);
    String playlistName = edtCreateNamePlaylist.getText().toString().trim();
    if (!(playlistName.isEmpty())) {
        boolean state = PlayListMethodHolder
                        .doPlaylistExists(getContext(), playlistName);
        if (!state) {
            PlayListMethodHolder.createPlaylist(getContext(), playlistName);
            dismiss();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "This name is already exists.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Empty name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
 }
});
```

**Finally,** this is a class for holding all methods of creating or deleting PlayLists

**PlayListMethodHolder.java**

```
public class PlayListMethodHolder {

  public static void createPlaylist(Context context, String playlistName) {

    String[] projectionName = new String [] {
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATA,
    };

    ContentValues nameValues = new ContentValues();
    nameValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, playlistName);
    nameValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_ADDED, 
                             System.currentTimeMillis());
    nameValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DATE_MODIFIED, 
                                System.currentTimeMillis());
    Uri uri = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
            .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, nameValues);

    if (uri != null) {
        context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver()
                .query(uri, projectionName, null, null, null);
        context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }
}

// Delete single playlist from list
public static void deletePlaylist (@NonNull final Context context, long playlistId){

    String playlistid = String.valueOf(playlistId);
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID + "=?";
    String[] whereVal = {playlistid};
    resolver.delete(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, where, 
                    whereVal);

    return ;
}


// get Playlist names
public static void getplaylistList(Context context, ArrayList<Playlist> plist) {
    Cursor playlistCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);
    if (playlistCursor != null && playlistCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int idColumn = playlistCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID);
        int titleColumn = playlistCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME);

        do {
            long thisId = playlistCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = playlistCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            plist.add(new Playlist(thisId, thisTitle));
        } while (playlistCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

[Tap to see **PlayList Design** View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPTYy.png)

Comment: My solution calls a AsyncTask, where deletion takes place in doInBackground and once completed in onPostExecute  I update the my viewmodel         viewModel.setId(mId,media_uri,datacolumns,selection, selectionArgs, sort_order); so everything is refreshed. Posting all elements would be too messy

Comment: I used this article and adapted the code a little 
https://medium.com/@JasonCromer/making-room-less-database-queries-using-the-new-android-architecture-components-81180ba6e7e0